# Deploying Amazon Textract application via Sagemaker

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, amazon-textract

I am trying to build an application via Amazon Textract that extracts the textual information from Images and validates the text. I am searching for a way to deploy the application via Sagemaker but could not find any method to deploy the application. The models built on TensorFlow, PyTorch, Sklearn, etc. can be deployed via Sagemaker. How do we deploy the Textract application via Sagemaker?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Textract is a managed service, deployed and operated by an AWS service team on their infrastructure. When using Amazon Textract, you don't have infrastructure to deploy yourself, just use one of its API. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/latest/dg/API_Operations.html